# Botão JavaScript em Animate CC

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela no Animate CC, a tela são 12 botões e quando o usuário "clica" em todos e no final do contador executa a a função de destravar a tela.

Oque esta acontecendo, é que se ele clicara em apenas 1 botão 12 vezes libera a função, estou precisando de fazer com que o botão só soma uma vez quando "clicado".

Obrigado!!

Código:

```
var contador = 0;

function verificaAvanco() {

  contador = contador + 1;
  if (contador == 12)
    window.parent.postMessage('destravaSlide', '*');
}

this.b1.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f1');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b2.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_2.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f2');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b3.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_3.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_3() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f3');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b4.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_4.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_4() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f4');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b5.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_5.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_5() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f5');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b6.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_6.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_6() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f6');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b7.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_7.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_7() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f7');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b8.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_8.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_8() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f8');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b9.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_9.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_9() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f9');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b10.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_10.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_10() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f10');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b11.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_11.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_11() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f11');
  verificaAvanco();
}

this.b12.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_12.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_12() {
  this.gotoAndStop('f12');
  verificaAvanco();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala Amigo,

Acredito que pode fazer a validação de forma diferente.

Atualmente sua validação está sendo feita através do contator, com isso você não tem controle do botão clicado, certo?

O que você pode fazer, é criar uma VAR do tipo Array com 12 posições e a cada botão clicado você adiciona o valor na posição respectiva.

```
var nome_Array = new Array(12);

function verificaAvanco() {


  if (nome_Array.toString() == '1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'){

    window.parent.postMessage('destravaSlide', '*');
}

this.b1.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler() {

  btn = Number(this.name.slice(1,this.name.length));
  nome_Array[btn-1]= '1'; 

  this.gotoAndStop('f1');

  verificaAvanco();

}
```

Vai ficar um pouco Manual, mas supre o que você precisa. 
A outras formas de se fazer, mas com base no seu código , creio que lhe ajude.